# Obtaining Pixel from the right-click event in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

In the 'click' event with the left mouse button I have the variable 'pixel' (an array with x and y), which can be used by 'forEachFeatureAtPixel':

`map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function (feature, layer) {})`

In contrast, in the event "contextmenu" is not there at all and I cannot use the function "forEachFeatureAtPixel". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! We can you can use getEventPixel function to obtain Pixel.

```
map.getEventPixel(event)
```

So this is the code that gets all the features on that spot:

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(event), function (feature, layer) {})
```